# Issue creating sylink for serial device on Linux (`'Inappropriate ioctl for device'`)

Tags: linux, usb, pyserial, rules

I am using multiple USB devices connected to an Ubuntu machine and I would like to create a symlink to their corresponding device file so that I can read from these devices in Python.

For example, for the device "ka3305p" I created the rules file `/etc/udev/rules.d/ka3305p.rules`.

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="0416", ATTR{idProduct}=="5011", SYMLINK+="ka3305p", MODE="0660", GROUP="dialout"
```

When I plug in the device, I see a symlink `/dev/ka3305p` appear:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root              15 Sep 21 10:08 ka3305p -> bus/usb/001/003
```

However, when I try to read from this file in python I get an error message:

```
def __init__(self,portname='/dev/ka3305p'):
    self.ser = serial.Serial(
        port=portname,
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
    )
```

`SerialException: Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')`

Can I change the rules file to avoid this error?

I can read / communicate with the device normally if I use the device file `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: I suspect making a udev rule isn't worth it for most people since you can just use the symbolic links created by the kernel in `/dev/serial/by-id/`.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to solve this issue, apparently, I had to use `ATTRS` instead of `ATTR` in the rules file. This fixed the problem and I can now read normally from the device using the symlink.

Comment: That is interesting that that solved it.  Does the symlink still point to `bus/usb/001/003` or is it pointing to something more serial-specific?